# wamp like debugging on lamp in ubuntu

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, wamp, lamp

Recently I installed LAMP (installed each one of them separately). I want a debugging tool like what wamp has on my lamp. so that tracing and showing errors be like wamp or better than that. how can I achieve this?
(wamp and lamp => apache,mysql,php)

Comment: If you mean WAMPServer that uses XDEBUG. That also works on a linux.

Comment: so its xdebug? the thing I should install?

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: ok thanks. so if you send your answer I can mark it as the selected one.